# Meaning of had better

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have to convert the following sentence into its imquoted indirect form for narration.

> "You'd better leave the dog alone," the man said.

Which one of the following two is correct?

> The man warned me to leave the dog alone.
>
> The man said I should leave the dog alone.

According to me second one is correct because in the original sentence there is some kind of suggestion. And **should** indicates suggestion. But according to my book first one is correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Had better* is a strong expression. We use it if we think there will be negative results if someone does not do what is desired or suggested. It seems to be even stronger than "You should...". I agree with Benjamin Harman, who implies that -

> It's a warning. "Had better" is idiomatic. It's always a warning
>   because if it doesn't expressly say so, it always implies "or else,"
>   that being a form of warning or threat that can remain vague as it
>   needn't continue on to explain what is meant by "else."

Therefore, the first sentence seems more appropriate.